# mysql select curdate

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table_name` 
ORDER BY  `table_name`.`dtn` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30

id      dt         dtn 
23  2012-01-20  2012-04-20
22  2011-12-19  2012-01-19
```

I need to check, which users do I need to visit this month. 
Example: This user visited on d/m/y 19/12/2011 and sheduled for next visit 19/01/2012.
Last visit was on 20/01/2012 and next one sheduled for 19/04/2012.

The problem: month is now JANUARY = 1 and I want to show all users that I need to visit this month.
When I use SQL select statement like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE MONTH(dtn) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(dtn) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

user is listed because in the past were scheduled for january.

In January, this user should not be listed because last scheduled date is 2012-04-20.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE MONTH(dtn) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(dtn) = YEAR(CURDATE())AND  (dtn>=CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

This SQL finds the rows with `dtn` this month that don't have any corresponding row with `dt` in the same month:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
table_name t2
ON
t1.dtn = t2.dt AND t2.dt IS NULL
WHERE MONTH(t1.dtn) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(t1.dtn) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```